# How to render the German word 'pflegen' in French?

Tags: traduction, informatique, allemand

I am looking for a French verb which conveys the meaning of the German word 'pflegen'. In particular in the IT sense of maintaining data (Datenpflegen) by keeping data up-to-date and consistent. I'm also looking for related words such as 'Daten einpflegen' (Data entry).

Comment: Google translates gives me *maintenir* which goes well with *maintenance* (*to mantain*). Is there something wrong with that ? or what is the nuance you wanna convey ? (*Daten einpflegen* can be *saisir* or *entrer* *des données*.)

Comment: Thanks! Does 'les données sont maintenues' sound right to you?

Comment: Nope, I'd say "*quelqu'un* (or *on*) *maintient les données*" (or *“on s'occupe de maintenir les données”*), but after some thought, it doesn't shock me much, and maybe it would sound right so someone who actually manages data in french. Hopefully someone who speaks german can see exactly what you mean?

Comment: I was also thinking of “entretenir”.

Answer (score 5):

As a native German, here are my thoughts:

I'm not sure if any French word does have a similar figurative meaning as *einpflegen* does have, but the suggested word **maintenir** sounds quite OK to me. Especially because there are a lot of results on Google for *maintenir* and *données* in context with SQL and SAP.

Comparing back-translations to German *instand halten*, *aufrechterhalten* and such are also expressing what you want to say. Additionally, Pons translates *Pflege and Wartung* with *entretien et maintenance* and *Programmwartung* with *maintenance du programme*.

As comments point out, *entretien* doesn't actually fit in context of data. It is more appropriate when talking about maintaining roads or such. The English *maintenance* is AFAIK also more about maintaining machines, roads etc., not software or data. However, I consider *maintenance* as barely suitable for *Datenpflege*.

Hence another, perhaps better, possibility might be **mise à jour des données**. It simply means *to update* and this is the closest match I came across in my Google search.

Last but not least, a translation I'd consider as appropriate for *einpflegen* is **saisir**. It means *to supply* or *to put in* texts, values etc.

Answer (score 4):

I'm no German speaker myself, but from what you have explained, I would translate *Datenpflegen* into *Maintenir des données à jour*.

As for *Daten einpflegen*, it could be translated to *Entrée / Introduction de données*, or *Entrer / Introduire des données* for the verbal form.

**Edit:** User Em1 came up with an even better translation for *Daten einpflegen* : *Saisie de données* / *Saisir des données*.

Comment: lol - a programmer's nightmare. You squeeze 'Datenpflege' into a field on the screen, send it for translation and get back 'Maintenir des données à jour'! German really is quite compact - sometimes ;-)

Comment: @paul: Since you are looking for the substantive, “maintenance des données” should be enough (not quite as compact as the German though).

Comment: I'd rather use *Maintien* instead of *Maintenance* when talking about data...

Answer (score 2):

'La maintenance' grates horribly on my ears as Frenglish, but it is absolutely what French engineers call it.  So 'maintenir les donnees' would be totally correct.  But entretenir calls rags and polish to mind :-), or something you'd do to your car.  Another vote for 'maintenir', in short.

Answer (score -2):

I don't speak German at all but, by your English description, it seems that *« synchronisation des données »* could match the meaning.

If it can't fit in the label, you can use *« synchro des données »* or even *« MAJ données »*.

Comment: *Synchronisation* is also a German word and since the German connotation is different to what is being asked, I guess it's same in French.

Comment: Totally second that, synchronisation is not the same at all than maintainir.